# Opencv cross compilation error , when tried to enable GTK+ support

Tags: opencv, cmake, gtk, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile Opencv for ARM.By using cmake.
I could successfully compile the opencv libraries without enabling the GTK+ support, but when i tried it to enable the GTK+ support (by adding the command -DWITH_GTK=ON ).
Then i am encountered with an error

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and Opencv version 2.4.9.
I have already installed the GTK library
The cmake command that i used is :
    cmake -DSOFTFP=ON -DENABLE_NEON=ON -DWITH_GTK=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake ../../..

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so
/opt/armv7/codesourcery/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/../../../..     
/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtk-x11-2.0 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you installed gtk headers too? (*dev* package)

Comment: @  karlphillip Yes, I have installed the gtk hedders with this command  "sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev".

Comment: @vin i have the same error, did you solved it?